# Async y await retornan el catch de la función que llamo y no de la principal

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy usando por primera vez async y await, las promesas con then si las he utilizado más, pero al usar async await tengo alguna duda a la hora de gestionar el catch.

En primer lugar tengo una función principal **(FuncionLanzar)** que es la encargada de llamar al resto de funciones que lanzan una serie de peticiones a una API y realizan un tratamiento de los datos.

Tiene que ser un proceso secuencial ya que recupero token, se lo envió a la segunda etc.

Esta es mi función principal:

```
const FuncionLanzar = async() => {
    try {
        const resp = await postToken()
        var access_token = resp.data.access_token;
        var token = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
        const resp2 = await getStations(token)
        var datos = resp2.data;
        for (let j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
            const id_stacions = datos[j].id_station;
            const FiwareService = datos[j].Fiware_Service;
            const FiwareServicePath = datos[j].Fiware_ServicePath;
            const lastdata = await getLastData(token, id_stacions)
            var json = lastdata.data.data;
            const Jformat_fiware = await FormatFiware(json)
            const envio = await PostFiware(Jformat_fiware, id_stacions, FiwareService, FiwareServicePath);
            console.log("Envio correcto de los datos");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en el enviooooooooooo' + error)
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email enviado: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

El problema es que nunca lleva a este catch a enviar un correo cuando encuentra un error o incluso si pongo un console.log a mostrar la información del error. Ya que en las funciones que llamo utilizó axios para hacer las peticiones, también tiene try async await y cuando falla me devuelve ese catch y no el de la función principal.

Ejemplo de función:

```
const getStations = async(token) => {
    var config = {
        headers: { "accept": "application/json", "Authorization": token },
    };
    try {
        return await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, config)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

No quiero poner el envío de correo en cada catch de las funciones que son llamadas (getStations), lo más lógico es que el catch de la función principal (FuncionLanzar) gestione los errores en su catch, pero entiendo que al encontrar un error en la función llamada (getStations) de ese error y termina el proceso.

Como podria realizar esto? eliminando el try y catch de las funciones que llamó y dejando solo el de la función principal?

No se si quedo muy claro.

**Edit01**

Hola de nuevo, he probado a eliminar todos los try y catch de las funciones que son llamadas y de esta forma si utiliza el catch de mi función principal, no se si es la forma correcta, pero por ahora funciona.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, prueba usando un nombre diferente para los objetos de error. Sucede que el primer bloque `try ... catch` declaras tu obejto de error con el nombre `error`, luego dentro de tu `catch` tienes una función (`sendMail`) que hace un llamado a otra función `callback` a la cual le estás pasando un objeto de error con el mismo nombre que el que tenías en tu sentencia `catch`. Prueba cambiando este nombre (y por lo tanto también el nombre dentro de la función `callback`), y comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: eso no funciona...:(

Comment: El problema que yo le veo en tu metodo getStations es que recoges la exepcion pero en ningun caso la levantas para pasarla hacia arriba(FuncionLanzar) para procesarlo. [Aqui](https://jsbin.com/wixowixozo/edit?html,js,output) te hice un ejemplo.

Comment: pero entonces el error lo esta lancando la funcion    throw Error("La funcion send ha lanzado una exepcion") no lo controla el catch de la funcion main verdad?

Comment: Publicare una respuesta para aclararte las dudas, porque sino se hace muy largo explicarlo por aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basandome en el codigo que has publicado, te explicare que estas haciendo mal.

Digamos que tenemos la funciona main que llama a las demas.

```
const FuncionLanzar = async() => {
    try {
        const resp = await postToken()
        var access_token = resp.data.access_token;
        var token = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
        const resp2 = await getStations(token)
        var datos = resp2.data;
        for (let j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
            ...
            const lastdata = await getStations(token, id_stacions) // getStations como ejemplo
            ....
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en el enviooooooooooo' + error)
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email enviado: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ahora vamos a ver que hace la funcion getStations.

Como ves todo el codigo esta envuelto en un `try catch`, por lo cual aquí tenemos dos posibilidades

1. Manejar el error en la misma funcion(getStations)
2. Pasar la exepcion hacia arriba.

```js
const getStations = async(token) => {
  var config = {
      headers: { "accept": "application/json", "Authorization": token },
  };
  try {
      return await axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, config)
  } catch (error) {
      //Fijate que aqui no levantas la exepcion, y por eso en el metodo 
      //padre no ocurre nada, ya que da por entendido que la exepcion se 
      //proceso correctamente.
      console.error(error)

      //En tu caso harias esto para pasar la exepcion al padre.
      throw error
  }
}
```

En tu caso lo que te interesa es que en la funcion `FunctionLanzar` puedas procesar todas las exepciones que pueden ocurrir.

Te dejo otro ejemplo que espero a que te ayude mas a entenderlo.

```
function send(){
  algun_func() // No existe: ReferenceError exception
}


function main(){
  try {
    //Llamamos a una funcion, que produce un error
    send()
  }catch(err){
    //Recogemos cualquier error
    console.log(err)
   //Aquí es donde enviarias el correo.
  }
}

main()
```

Te dejo la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch) que lo explica todo muy bien.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y que me haya explicado bien.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Hola, gracias por le ayuda. Entonces si no he entendido mal puedo usar el       throw error en mi funcion para enviar el error al main o solo usar un try y catch en la  función main para poder gestionar todos los fallos en esta verdad?

Comment: Si, aunque puedes usar try catch en las otras funciones tambien.

Comment: Perfecto, entendido. Muchas gracias.